# how to add non-generated styles to tailwind.css component?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I have a problem that I want to apply styles to a component from props but these styles are not generated, how do I apply them? I can provide the code if needed.(applying only default tailwind colors like black and white)

i'm searched a lot of forums but none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful to see your code but,

To use variables inside of your components, you can use `` className={`$myvar`} `` .

With this in mind, you should be able to use a variable that you've obtained from your component props.